# Unable to resolve hostname for Redhat Linux server

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, dhcp, resolv.conf

I've setup a Linux Red Hat server and would like to use it by referring to its hostname instead of the static IP.

eg. `ssh admin@myhostname.blah.di.blah`, instead of `ssh admin@XX.XXX.XX.XXX`

but I get a message:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname myhostname Name or service not known.
```

OR

If I do a `nslookup` from a windows client I get this such that it can detect the IP but I see dhcp-IP instead of my set hostname:

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  1903:ad:8s10::fd
Name:    dhcp-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.blah.di.blah
Address:  xx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

As per several other stackoverflow posts, I set the hostname in:

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

as

`DHCP_HOSTNAME=myhostname.blah.di.blah`

I made the changes and did a `dhclient -r` followed by `dhclient eth0` but no luck.

Also, my `/etc/hosts` file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost localhost.localdomain
xx.xxx.xx.xxx myhostname.blah.di.blah
```

Comment: Did you add the hostname to your /etc/hosts file?

Comment: Yes, I had: `127.0.0.1  localhost localhost.localdomain
xx.xxx.xx.xxx myhostname.blah.di.blah`.. updated description to include this.

Comment: Ok.. what happens when you ping the domain?

Comment: When I ping IP - I get the correct response, pinging domain returns `ping: unknown host myhostname.blah.di.blah`

Comment: Ok one last thing you can try is changing your ~/.ssh/config file to associate the IP address with the host.. This is definitely a DNS problem...

Comment: It doesn't work either. I'm not sure where is the "dhcp-xx-xxx-xx-xxx" bit coming from, it just needs to be populated with 'myhostname'. Don't know which config. needs to be updated to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to reach the system by hostname from another system, it will not work. You will need to either set up a DNS server on your network and add these entries, or manually add the hostname to the hosts file of the remote system you are using.